# MySQL query: generate a report of the top votes for the each food type

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a user table with id, username and food_id columns. The idea is the user stored their favorite food and we come up with a league table of foods and I want to generate a report of the top votes for the each food type. I am using MySQL and PHP.

For clarity, here is an example of the table:

```
 id  food_id   username
 1   1         Bob
 2   100       Jane
 3   200       Andy
 4   1         Maggy
 5   100       Rich
 6   100       Mick
 7   1         Kevin
```

How do I write the query to list the foods that have the most votes. I want to limit the result to x number, say top 100. In this case I want the result to be as follows:

food_id   score
1         3
100       4

I hope the question is clear enough. The query is beyond me but I am sure it must be possible to do it using DISTINCT and COUNT in some way or other. Perhaps it's sub queries?

Comment: can you please give us a more specific explanation? Give us the other tables involved in this system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select food_id, count(*) score
   from myTable
group by food_id
order by score desc limit 100



SELECT F.food_name,
    COUNT(*) AS score
FROM myTable AS M 
    INNER JOIN food_table AS F
        ON F.food_id = M.food_id
GROUP BY F.food_name
ORDER BY score DESC limit 100
```

Comment: Thanks very much mate. All these answers worked but I copied and pasted yours so I give you the answer tick! Thanks again, so simple when you know how!

Comment: Hey a quick additional question. How do I join that query to give me the food name instead of the ID. My food table has food_id and food_name columns. Hope you get this comment! Cheers, Rich

Comment: SELECT F.food_name,
        COUNT(*) AS score
    FROM myTable AS M 
        INNER JOIN food_table AS F
            ON F.food_id = M.food_id
    GROUP BY F.food_name
    ORDER BY score DESC limit 100

Answer (score 1):

`select count(*) as top100 from table group by food_id order by top100 desc limit 100`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   f.`food_id`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM     `fav_food_table` f
GROUP BY f.`food_id`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
LIMIT    100;
```